# Prove matrix identity by induction

Tags: induction

Let $\lambda_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ og $\lambda_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Show by induction in $k$ that
    \begin{equation*}
  A^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_2^{k-1}-\lambda_1^{k-1} & \lambda_2^k-\lambda_1^k\\
    \lambda_2^k-\lambda_1^k & \lambda_2^{k+1}-\lambda_1^{k+1}
  \end{pmatrix}
  , k>0
\end{equation*}
    when
    \begin{equation*}
  A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \in\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}

**My attempt**

When $k=1$ I get:
\begin{equation*}
  A^1=
  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{align*}
  A^1&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda_2^0-\lambda_1^0 & \lambda_2-\lambda_1\\
     \lambda_2-\lambda_1 & \lambda_2^2-\lambda_1^2
   \end{pmatrix}\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
     \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} & 1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\left(1+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
   \end{pmatrix}\\
 &=
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1\\
     1 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Therefore the statement is true for $k=1$. Now I assume that the statement is true for $k=n$. Then I have to prove that it is true for $k=n+1$, but I can't get it to work for $k=n+1$. Can you help?

Comment: To get $A^{n+1}$, just multiply $A^n$ with $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Just use what induction means, write $A^{n+1} = A^n\times A$, you know both terms in the product, plug them in, find $A^{n+1}$. Also, observe that $\lambda_i$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1 = 0$. Thus, $$\lambda_i^n+\lambda_i^{n-1} = \lambda_i^{n+1}$$

---

$$A^{n+1} =A^n\times A =
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_2^{n-1}-\lambda_1^{n-1} & \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n\\
        \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n & \lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1}
      \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        0&1\\
        1&1
      \end{pmatrix} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
      \begin{pmatrix}
       \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n& \lambda_2^{n-1}-\lambda_1^{n-1} +  \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n \\
        \lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1}& \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n +\lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1}
      \end{pmatrix}
    $$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
      \begin{pmatrix}
       \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n& \left(\lambda_2^{n-1} +  \lambda_2^n\right)-\left(\lambda_1^{n-1}+\lambda_1^n\right) \\
        \lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1}& \left(\lambda_2^n+\lambda_2^{n+1}\right)-\left(\lambda_1^n +\lambda_1^{n+1}\right)
      \end{pmatrix}
    $$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
      \begin{pmatrix}
       \lambda_2^n-\lambda_1^n& \lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1} \\
        \lambda_2^{n+1}-\lambda_1^{n+1}& \lambda_2^{n+2}-\lambda_2^{n+2}
      \end{pmatrix}
    $$

Comment: Why is $(\lambda_2^{n-1}+\lambda_2^n)=\lambda_2^{n+1}$?

Comment: As $\lambda_2$ is a root of $x^2-x-1$, $\lambda_2^2 = \lambda_2 + 1$. Now, multiply this equation by $\lambda_2^{n-1}$, then, we have $\lambda_2^{n-1}+\lambda_2^n = \lambda_2^{n+1}$